# Custom font disappears on App Store version, but worked 100% during development builds. Spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, sprite-kit, xcode12

I've installed a custom font into my spritekit game. Tested it in simulator & iPhone5,7,11 pro. No problem. Works 100%.

So I finished my app and uploaded it to App Store connect. No problem.

Waited the normal time for apple to review my app. Got approved. No Problem.

So I go ahead and download my app for the first time from App Store. - CUSTOM FONT IS GONE!

I've done the following to make it work during development:

- Made sure the added font's target membership is checked
- Made sure the font's name is added to the info.plist (Fonts provided by application).
- Made sure I'm using the correct font name.
- Made sure the font is included in the "Copy bundle Resources" under Build phases.

-- All is good. Tests 100%.

What I've tried since realising the Font is not correct on the App Store version. (And by the way, I have to wait for Apple to review my new version every time to see whether the little changes I made had an effect.)

- Added a ghost label to Scene.sks . (The Font name is found in the dropdown list)
- Used a different Custom Font.

-- Same issue

I'm suspecting an issue on Apple's side.

Is there by any chance someone that has come across this issue before?

Comment: This is a case where using TestFlight would be very helpful... you can register accounts (such as for your testing devices) as "Internal Testers" and you can install the app immediately after it's been initially processed - no need to wait for Apple review. I'd suggest creating a new "test only" app with just enough code to determine whether or not your custom font is working. That way you can very quickly make changes to try and figure out the issue.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great idea. Didn't think I would have an issue like this as every thing tested correct. Will give feedback once the issue is sorted.

Comment: Logged a call with DTS. Their reply is that they also believe it is a bug. I filed a bug report via the Feedback assistant page.